# What use is the final modifer on method/constructor parameters

Tags: java

Hello
What use is the final modifier on a method/constructor parameter?

Ex:

```
class someClass {
    private final double some; // I understand the use of final in this context, immutability etc..

    public someClass(final double some) {
        // I don't understand what purpose is served by making "some" final
        this.some = some;
    }

    public void someMethod(final double some) {
        // I don't understand what purpose is served by making "some" final
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 main situations when you need it:

1) you want to use the parameter inside local class (usually, anonymous class), like:

```
public void foo(final String str) {
    Printer p = new Printer() {
        public void print() {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    };
    p.print();
}
```

2) you like the style when every variable which is not modified is marked with the `final` word (it is generally a good practice to keep as much things immutable as possible ).

Comment: +1 for the first point. A comment about the second one: final reference are not guaranteeing immutability

Comment: @jimi: but it's the way to achieve immutability.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the purpose is that you cannot asign the parameter with anything

```
public someClass(T some) {

        some = null; //You can do this. Maybe you want to use the variable `some` later on in your constructor
    }

public someClass(final T some) {

        some = null; //You can't do this. If you want to reuse `some` you can't.
    }
```

Useful? Not much. Normally you don't use arguments variables. But in some special situations you may want to be able to do it.

Anyway, if some does `new someClass(mySome)` , `mySome` will never be changed although inside the function you assign values to the argument. There is no such thing as `pass-by-refrence` in Java. Variables are primitives or references to objects, never the object itself.

Comment: Since it's a valid point, imho, it's useless. You cannot accidentally assign anything to the parameter and not to see it. (If there were a possibility to pass by reference in java then I would say that your point is the most possible reason to use final in the described situation).

Comment: @Roman haha, yeah I was reading my own answer and I thought the same as you, so I edited while you were replying.

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of the function, the some variable is a constant.

Another benefit would be to prevent variable reuse. That is to say "some" should be used for only one purpose.